# cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup file smaller than Payload Offset?

Tags: encryption, luks

I created test LUKs container in a file, the luksDump says

> MK bits:        256
>   Payload offset: 4096

implying that the header is 4096*512 = 2MiB
but the file produced by

> cryptsetup luksHeaderBackup --header-backup-file header.backup /dev/loop0

is only 1052672  (1MiB + 4096)

Why ?

Answer (score 1):

The payload start is rounded up for alignment purposes. How much can be controlled by providing the `--align-payload` option to luksFormat.